# Multiple bindings to the same provider instance with Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have two interfaces A and B and B is extending A.

I have one provider being able to provide instances whose Class is implementing B (and consequently A).

I would like to bind Provider to B.class (straightforward) and to A.class with an Annotation  in a singleton scope.

```
bind(B.class).toProvider(MyBImplProvider.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
bind(A.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("B")).toProvider(MyBImplProvider.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

How to return the same instance from the provider no matter if I inject through B.class or through A.class+Annotation. For instance, I'd like to be able to define constuctors as

```
@Inject
C(B param)
```

or

```
@Inject
C(@Named("B") param)
```

In both case, I'd like param to be valuated with the same singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about making your A Provider depend on the B provider you've defined above?

```
@Provides 
@Named("B")
A provideA(Provider<B> bProvider) {
  return bProvider.get();
}
```

That should work since you said B extends A. You might need to play around with the `@Named` bit.

Another option would be to use a [`toInstance(yourObject)`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html) binding. But this makes it messy to inject any dependencies into that object. You would have to use [`Binder#requestInjection()`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#requestInjection%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: I don't have it. Will Guice inject the Provider<B> ?

Comment: Yes it will. Try it? (The method has to go on a Guice module, see [@Provides methods](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods))